# How to fix error objects are not valid react child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I am trying map through an object with the goal to render the key and their value inside a p tag. I am having the error message object are not valid react child.

How can I overcome this error?

```
        <div className="d-flex flex-wrap">
              {
              
              Object.keys(features).map((item,index) => {           
                  console.log('type',item);
                  console.log(features[item]);
                  

                   return   <p key={item} className="fw-bold bg-light fs-6 text-primary m-1 p-2">{{[item]:features[item]}}</p> 
                      
               
              })
              }
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is because the code

```
{{[item]:features[item]}}
```

actually results to an object. So child of `<p>` tag is an object. You can solve it by using Template literals inside `<p>` tag

```
 <div className="d-flex flex-wrap">
          {
         
          Object.keys(features).map((item,index) => {           
              console.log({[item]:features[item]});
              console.log(features[item]);
              

               return   <p key={item} className="fw-bold bg-light fs-6 text-primary m-1 p-2" >{`{${item}: ${features[item]}}`}</p> 
                  
           
          })
          }
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this section of React [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx), it is said that:

> You can put any valid JavaScript expression inside the curly braces in JSX

Moreover `{[item]:features[item]}` itself is not a valid expression, according to [this list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#expressions)

So instead, you have to embed 2 expressions, `item` and `features[item]`

```
return (
  <p key={item} className="fw-bold bg-light fs-6 text-primary m-1 p-2">
    {item}: {features[item]}
  </p>
)
```

Comment: hi @hgb123 , i did have it set this way initially but it gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the double brackets in your code

Use only one brackets like this

```
{[item]:features[item]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is JSON

```
{[item]:features[item]}
```

If you meant to render the JSON as a string then do like this.

```
JSON.stringify({[item]:features[item]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
Object.keys(features).map((item) => {   
return <p>  {item} : {features[item]}</p>
}
```